# How does the StackOverflow CMD-K key binding work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does StackOverflow take highlighted text and toggle between code formatted and not code formatted? Any ideas how they approach this problem? Thanks

Comment: Magic... It's a feature of the online text editor being used. Works no different than 'bold' or 'italic' in any other editor, like TinyMCE

Comment: This magic I didn't know. Was indenting in an external editor.  :-)

Comment: Thanks Marc, if it wasn't Magic I wouldn't ask. Now lets see who knows the magicians trick... I can handle the keybinding, the rest is a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

It is done within the [Markdown.Editor.js](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/source/browse/Markdown.Editor.js)

Lines of Importance to the code button:

```
1194-1196
1263-1321
1368-1372
1387-1402
1418
1905-1965 // this one is the most important
```

You may get more answers if you are more specific in what you are actually asking for.